# Maven - No plugin found for prefix 'tomcat7' in the current project and in the plugin groups

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I've created a Maven project. This is the structure:

```
-parent
    -core
    -web
```

but when I try to deploy with the command `mvn tomcat7:deploy`, I get the following error:

```
No plugin found for prefix 'tomcat7' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
```

I put this configuration in the pom.xml (of the web project):

```xml
<build>
    <finalName>MavenWeb</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: You are probably executing this command NOT from your web project.

Comment: @Aleksandr thank you for your answer, you were right. Now I am trying to solve another problem "Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection to http://127.0.0.1:8080 refused: Connection refused" I am trying to reach the solution.

Comment: Version concretization in <i>tomcat7-maven-plugin</i> **pom.xml** helped me. There was `<version>${tomcat7-maven-plugin.version}</version>`. I changed it to `<version>2.2</version>` and all worked!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Plugins goals can be called using their 'FQN': *groupId:artifactId:version:goal* or, if applicable, shorter commands (many variants available).
Using only the short name of a plugin (in your *tomcat7:deploy*, tomcat7 is the short name, deploy being the goal/mojo) is applicable if:

1)  the groupId of the plugin is contained in the known plugin groups of Maven. *org.apache.maven.plugins* being in the list by default.

OR

the pom.xml of the project you're invoking the Maven command on declares the plugin

2) the artifactId is *[short-name]-maven-plugin* or *maven-[short-name]-plugin* (*maven-[short-name]-plugin* being 'reserved' for plugins provided by Maven project.

That explains why *mvn compiler:compile* can work out of the box on any project, but not *tomcat7:deploy*

In your case, the second condition is true, so you just have to declare the plugin on the project you're launching the command on, or add this to your user *settings.xml* file:

```
<pluginGroups>
  <pluginGroup>org.apache.tomcat.maven</pluginGroup>
</pluginGroups>
```

[See here for more info](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html)

Comment: There is no need to change `settings.xml` file if plugin is defined in pom.

Comment: You're right, I'm editing the answer to include this

Comment: What does "you just have to declare the plugin on the project you're launching the command on" mean for the pom.xml? How do I do this exactly?

Comment: That means that if the plugin you want to invoke from the command line, using the _short notation_ (not the FQN) is already defined in the _pom.xml_ of the module you're invoking the command from, the `<pluginGroups>` is not needed.

Comment: I would like to add that the *settings.xml* file is inside the apache-maven-X.X.X\conf\ folder, because It wasn't easy to find it, being a begginer myself and that info could be useful for someone else (even though after all I get it working with the maven-plugin-dependency tip ;) )

Answer (score 5):

The reason why you get that error is because you simply have not installed the Tomcat7 plugin. Here's what you can do (I tested this on my test project and it works):

1. Add tomcat7 plugin dependency in your `pom.xml` file just like you have done.
2. Run either `mvn install`or `mvn package` to install that tomcat7 plugin
3. Now you should be able to run `mvn tomcat7:deploy`

I tested this solution with `mvn tomcat7:run` and it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 4):

It means tomcat7 plugin not found . Add this to your pom.xml.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error happens to have the plugin inside `<reporting>`, it should be located in `<build>`

Before:

```
<reporting>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
    <port>8080</port>
    <path>/</path>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</reporting>
```

After:

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
    <port>8080</port>
    <path>/</path>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

After I checked my pom.xml file, I made sure all my dependencies were selected in the build order under the JAVA Build Path [JAVA BUILD PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXLAD.png)

Comment: In general you may want to add a little more detail on how your answer solves the original issue

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error from using the file based idp.xml and formatting it!!!   Don't format it, use curl, or chrome and save the file from https://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml directly to spring-security-saml-1.0.2.RELEASE\sample\src\main\resources\metadata\idm.xml

Then in SecurityContext.cml

```
 <bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <!-- Example of classpath metadata with Extended Metadata -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource">
                                <constructor-arg value="/metadata/idp.xml"/>
                            </bean>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>

</bean>
```