# Can't find Flyway maven plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, flyway

In my pom.xml, I have:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration></configuration>
 </plugin>
```

to test the plugin, I'm doing:

```
mvn flyway:migrate
```

But I get an error:

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'flyway' in the current project and in the pl
ugin groups [org.wildfly.plugins, org.flywaydb.plugins, org.apache.maven.plugins
, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\me\.
m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
```

What am I missing from my pom? the flyway plugin IS in central.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24314847)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should run `mvn compile flyway:migrate` inside your project class path.

Suppose your has a project name `bar` that store inside `C:\project` directory.

- You should open command prompt and change change directories to `C:\project\bar`.
- Then, Run `mvn compile flyway:migrate` instead of use `mvn flyway:migrate`

See also, [First Steps: flywaydb with Maven](http://flywaydb.org/getstarted/firststeps/maven.html)

Comment: [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'flyway' in the current project

Answer (score 2):

In my case it says: DataSource not set! Check your configuration!
You should fill configuration tag:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <url>jdbc:h2:file:./target/foobar</url>
            <user>sa</user>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.191</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved the: mvn compile flyway:migrate but other annoyances with Flyway still exist.