# Flyway Maven plugin no longer working: No plugin found for prefix 'flyway' in the current project and in the plugin groups

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, flyway

Whenever I ran `mvn spring-boot:run` Flyway would pick up pending migrations in `/src/main/resources/db/migration/` automatically and run them. Now it doesn't. Even when I use `mvn compile` or `mvn package` it complains about a missing table - because the pending migration creates it! I try `mvn flyway:migrate` and it complains

> [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'flyway' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\Chloe.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

Here is the POM

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
  <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

https://flywaydb.org/documentation/plugins/springboot

I found this in the console output when running `spring-boot:run`:

```
2018-07-30 23:36:24.980  INFO 197376 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e24a304] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-07-30 23:36:24.987  INFO 197376 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'stringOrNumberMigrationVersionConverter' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$StringOrNumberToMigrationVersionConverter] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

Java 8, Mvn 3, Spring Boot 1.5.13

Comment: Have you tried clearing your .m2 folder ?

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27326016/cant-find-flyway-maven-plugin

Comment: @SnailPacer `mvn compile flyway:migrate` still gave the same error. And that question is for a vanilla Maven project, not a Spring Boot project.

Comment: Adding a flyway dependency isn't a flyway plugin. So trying the plugin will obviously fail as there is no plugin configured. What did you change which broke it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the Flyway Maven plugin to your POM first, before you can use it. See https://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/

Comment: @Chloe Trust me, my answer is correct. I am the one who wrote the docs you just referred to. Also see M. Deinium's comment to the question.

Comment: OK I added the plugin, but it gave me an error. Why isn't it using the values from `spring.datasource.*`? `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:5.1.4:migrate (default-cli) on project GalaxyAppShortUrl: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to connect to the database. Configure the url, user and password! -> [Help 1]`

Comment: I had to give the datasource properties on the command line. https://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/#system-properties It also changed the way checksums are calculated from v3 to v5 so I had to repair to recalculate them: `mvn flyway:repair -Dflyway.user=root -Dflyway.password= -Dflyway.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname -Dflyway.table=schema_version`.